# how to extract the child element from nested tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
I have a scenario in xml :

    <body>
        <div><i>italic</i>
            <div id ="88">
                <div id="4545">
                    <h3>hey h3</h3>
                    <xyz>XYZ</xyz>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  id="123">
            <h1>Example</h1>
                <div  id="1234">
                    <h1>heading 1</h1>
                    <p>computer</p>
                    <div>
                        <i>italic 2</i>
                        <div>
                            <h3>heading 3</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            <div  id="12345">
                <h1>heading 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

I need to apply the rule that div converted to section and the div in which h1 value is Example ,delete that h1 tag and add attribute class=<value of that h1> to section tag .

expected output:
    <body>
        <section>
            <i>italic<i>
        </section>
        <section class="hey h3">

             <xyz>XYZ</xyz>
        </section>
        <section class="example">
            <title>heading 1</title>
            <p>computer</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <i>italic 2</i>
        </section>
        <section>
        <h3>heading 3</h3>
        </section>
        <section >
            <title>heading 1</title>
        </section>
    </body>

my xslt:
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[h1='Example']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::h1)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/h1">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[h3='hey h3']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::h3)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/h3">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[not(h1='Example')]">
        <section>
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h1[.='Example']]">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">example</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::div)]"/>
        </section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[self::div]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[not(h3='hey h3')]">
        <section>
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h3[.='hey h3']]">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">richi rich</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::div)]"/>
        </section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[self::div]"/>
    </xsl:template>



actual output:
    <body>
        <section>
            <i>italic</i>
        </section>
        <section/>
        <section>
            <title>hey h3</title>
            <xyz>XYZ</xyz>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>Example</title>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>heading 1</title>
            <p>computer</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <i>italic 2</i>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>heading 3</title>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>heading 1</title>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Actually there are two scenarios :
    1. nested section should not be present and
    2. the condition that the  which is having  as "heading 1" then delete that tag from the div and add the attribute to the div with the value of  tag .

Could you please suggest what should I do here to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

next, match the `div` node which contains the target `h1` node

```
<xsl:template match="div[h1='Example']">
    <!-- apply child nodes except h1 -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::h1)]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and a template for `div` nodes which do not contain the target `h1` node

```
<xsl:template match="div[not(h1='Example')]">
    <section>
        <!-- set the attribute if the immediate preceding-sibling node is h1 -->
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h1[.='Example']]">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">example</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::div)]"/>
    </section>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[self::div]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and a template for the `h1` node

```
<xsl:template match="div/h1">
    <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
</xsl:template>
```

The whole stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[h1='Example']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::h1)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/h1">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[not(h1='Example')]">
        <section>
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h1[.='Example']]">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">example</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::div)]"/>
        </section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[self::div]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see it in action (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpb/3)

Comment: if i have some other sections except the mentioned one...this code applies a new section then again for other sections it will nested .

Comment: because there are some other divs which does not contain the h1 and it wrap up the other divs inside section .

Comment: Essentially, the code is right. I have added a few lines of code to beautify the output. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpb/2

Comment: yes..it is working fine. But if it is 3 or 4 level deep then it is not working

Comment: the nested div with italic child is missing in your required output

Comment: I have updated my code . If there is two conditions on the basis of which I need to add attribute to <div> tag. 1. if value of <h3> is hey h3 then delete that tag and add the attribute to the section with the value of h3.   2.   that I explained earlier. Now in this case I am unable to get the expected result. Could you please suggest.