# how to extract child elements from nested tag in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a scenario in xml :

```
<body>
<div><i>italic</i></div>
<div  id="123">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <div  id="1234">
        <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <p>computer</p>
        <div>
            <i>italic 2</i>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div  id="12345">
        <h1>heading 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to apply the rule that div converted to section and the div in which h1 value is Example ,delete that h1 tag and add attribute class= to section tag .

expected output:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <i>italic<i>
    </section>
    <section class="example">
        <title>heading 1</title>
        <p>computer</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <i>italic 2</i>
    </section>
    <section >
        <title>heading 1</title>
    </section>
</body>
```

my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="//div">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="div">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </section>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="div[h1 = 'Example']/h1" />
   <xsl:template match="div[h1 = 'Example']">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="div[h1 = 'example']">
   <section>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:value-of select="'example'" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      </section>
   </xsl:template>
```

actual output:

```
<section class="example">
    <section>
        <title>heading 1</title>
        <p>computer</p>
        <section>
            <i>italic 2</i>
        </section>
     </section>
     <section >
         <title>heading 1</title>
     </section>
</section>
```

Could you please suggest what should I do here to get the expected output.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938938/how-to-extract-the-child-element-from-nested-tags-using-xslt

Comment: Here is a section  <section class="example"> which is having class attribute but in other question I need a section tag without any attribute